# ERROR: Solver log: Unrecognized flag or missing argument: -AMPL

Tags: gurobi, pyomo

I am trying to use gurobi 8.0 with pyomo 5.5.  When solving a simple model as a test I get the following error:
ERROR: Solver log: Unrecognized flag or missing argument: -AMPL

```
from pyomo.environ import *

model = ConcreteModel()

model.x = Var([1,2], domain=NonNegativeReals)

model.OBJ = Objective(expr = 2*model.x[1] + 3*model.x[2])

model.Constraint1 = Constraint(expr = 3*model.x[1] + 4*model.x[2] >= 1)

solver = SolverFactory("gurobi_cl")
results = solver.solve(model)  #error here
model.solutions.store_to(results)
print(results)
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you are calling `SolverFactory('gurobi_cl')` rather than just `SolverFactory('gurobi')`?

Comment: Because using gurobi throws an error indicating the it can't find an executable.  My install of gurobi python package does not have gurobi.exe, but does have gurobi_cl.exe.

Comment: You say that you're using gurobi python? When you open a python prompt and type in `import gurobipy`, do you get an error message?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by using this solver call: solver = SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="python")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pyomo `SolverFactory` works by first looking to see if it has a custom solver interface registered under the name you provide to the factory.  If it does, it returns that solver interface.  If it doesn't, then it looks to see if it can find an executable on your PATH matching that name, and if it does, it assumes that the executable is an AMPL solver and returns the ASL interface.  If both of these fail, it returns an UnknownSolver object.

In your specific case, you are hitting the second branch. Unfortunately, `gurobi_cl` is not an ASL binary, resulting in the error you see.

There are several ways to interface with Gurobi: through LP files, through NL files, and directly through the Python bindings (in either a one-shot or persistent mode).  Each of these routes use different executables.  The `SolverFactory("gurobi")` is actually a wrapper that returns one of these specialized solvers, based on the `solver_io` flag.  The default is the LP file interface, which relies on the `gurobi.sh` interactive shell.

If you don't have `gurobi.sh` in your Gurobi install, you can use the other interfaces (the NL interface requires the `gurobi_ampl` executable, and the direct interface requires that the Python bindings are installed into your Python environment).  For your install, I would start with the "direct" interface:

```
solver = SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="direct")
# (or `solver_io="python"` in older Pyomo releases)
```

Comment: I was able to get it working with the io-"python" option.  Thanks!